# Using items with different numbers of response categories across time points in longitudinal modeling

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, measurement, psychology

I'm doing a cross-lagged panel modeling for three time points. For one specific construct of interest, I have three items that were used for across three time points, but the number of items used for the first two time points differs: 3-point likert scale for the first two time points (yes/agree, not sure, no/disagree), and than 5-point for the last time point (strongly agree, somewhat agree, neither agree nor disagree, somewhat disagree, strongly disagree).

May I compress the 5-point scale to a 3-point scale to make them more comparable, or should I just use different scales as is in the same cross-lagged panel model? My preference is combining some response categories of the 5-point scale (the first two categories to one; and the last two categories to one). The measurement invariance (configural, metric) looks good after combining them.

I've been trying to find some literature on this, but haven't been successful. I'd be grateful for any feedback!

Comment: Can you edit your question to add scale-point descriptions for the 3- and 5-item scales?  Perhaps threshold invariance constraints can be imposed if there thresholds that can be interpreted the same way in both scales.

Comment: Thank you! I just added the scale-point descriptions. Could you please elaborate on imposing threshold invariance constraints?